# problems with slim loading class

Tags: php, slim-4

I am doing my first project using SLIM in PHP. When calling a class I have the following error message:

**Error Message:**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: App\Controllers\CitasController:getAll is not resolvable in /var/www/html/slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php:170
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php(109): Slim\CallableResolver->assertCallable()
#1 /var/www/html/slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php(72): Slim\CallableResolver->resolveByPredicate() 
#2 /var/www/html/slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Routing/Route.php(366): Slim\CallableResolver->resolveRoute() 
#3 /var/www/html/slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(81): Slim\Routing\Route->handle() 
#4 /var/www/html/slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(81): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle() 
#5 /var/www/html/slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Routing/Route.php(341): Slim\MiddlewareDispatcher->handle() 
#6 /var/www/html/slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Routing/RouteRunner.php(84): Slim\Routing\Route->run() 
#7 /var/www/html/slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareDispatcher.php(81): Slim\Routing\RouteRunner->handle() 
#8 in /var/www/html/slim/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/CallableResolver.php on line 170
```

**Project Structure:**

[[image]]

1. composer.json

```
    {
        "require": {
            "slim/slim": "^4.9",
            "slim/psr7": "^1.5",
            "slim/php-view": "^3.1",
            "respect/validation": "^1.1",
            "php-di/php-di": "^6.0"
        },
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "App\\": "src/"
            }
        }
    }
```

2. index.php

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    require __DIR__ . '/../src/App/App.php';
```

3. App.php

```
    <?php
    use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
    require __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';
    $app = AppFactory::create();
    require __DIR__ . "/Routes.php";
    $app->run();
```

4. Routes.php

```
    <?php
    use Slim\Routing\RouteCollectorProxy;
    $app->group('/api',function(RouteCollectorProxy $group){
        $group->get('/citas','App\Controllers\CitasController:getAll');
    });

    $app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, $args) {
        $response->getBody()->write("Hello world!");
        return $response;
    });
```

5. CitasController.php

```
    <?php
    namespace App\Controllers;


    use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
    use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;


    class CitasController{
        
        public function getAall($request, $response, $arg){
            $response->getBody()->write("Hollaaa");
            return $response;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the Slim framework, however one thing I noticed is you have a typo in your function name. The function in `CitasController` is called `getAall` while your Routes file is referencing `getAll`

Comment: I tested your code and can confirm the main problem with this code is the typo mentioned in the comment by Sidney. You also have another (unrelated to this question) problem, which is not includinet `use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;` and `use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface as Request;` in Routes.php

Answer (score 0):

There's no error here about class loading issues. You've defined a route with a callable that isn't valid:

```
/**
 * @param mixed $resolved
 * @param mixed $toResolve
 *
 * @throws RuntimeException
 *
 * @return callable
 */
private function assertCallable($resolved, $toResolve): callable
{
    if (!is_callable($resolved)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(sprintf(
            '%s is not resolvable',
            is_callable($toResolve) || is_object($toResolve) || is_array($toResolve) ?
                json_encode($toResolve) : $toResolve
        ));
    }
    return $resolved;
}
```

The error complaints about `CitasController:getAll()` but you have `public function getAall($request, $response, $arg)`.

Comment: [Notation of `'ClassName:methodName'` is perfectly fine](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/routing.html#container-resolution) as the framework will handle creation of the the `ClassName` object and calling `methodName` method on it. The OP's is problem the typo you mentioned (I tested their code and it worked as expected after fixing the typo). Apart from the typo, other information you provided in your answer, although correct when not using Slim, is misleading in this case.

Comment: @Nima You are right, I had forgotten that custom [syntax](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v4/objects/routing.html#container-resolution). I'll remove the misleading information, thanks for noting it.